# Get spesific filed name in the $session codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to get the ID of the logged-in user , and i print out the following line

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->session->userdata());
```

The result is as follows :

```
Array
(
  [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1449132599
[lang] => english
[userdata] => User_model Object
    (
        [table] => er_users
        [primaryKey] => user_id
        [primaryLabel] => user_name
        [usertype] => user_type
        [rules] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => integer
                [user_type] => required|integer
                [user_name] => required|min_length[3]
                [user_email] => required|valid_email
                [user_pass] => min_length[8]|max_length[16]
                [user_pconf] => required|matches[user_pass]
                [user_mobile] => required|min_length[10]
                [user_avatar] => 
                [user_code] => required|integer
                [user_status] => required|integer
            )

        [forms] => Array
            (
                [*] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => user_id
                            )

                        [user_type] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => user_type
                                [type] => select:hasOne[Admin/Setting][value][name^=user_type]
                            )

                        [user_name] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => user_name
                            )

                        [user_email] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => user_email
                            )

                        [user_pass] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => user_pass
                                [type] => password
                            )

                        [user_pconf] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => user_pconf
                                [type] => password
                            )

                        [user_mobile] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => user_mobile
                                [type] => mobile
                            )

                        [user_avatar] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => user_avatar
                                [type] => select:hasOne[Admin/User::avatars][avatar]
                            )

                        [user_code] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => user_code
                            )

                        [user_status] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => user_status
                                [type] => select:hasOne[Admin/Setting][value][name^=user_status]
                            )

                    )

                [list] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_type] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_name] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_email] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_mobile] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_status] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [user_name] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_email] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_mobile] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [create] => Array
                    (
                        [user_type] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_name] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_email] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_pass] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_mobile] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_status] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [edit] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => hidden
                            )

                        [user_type] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_name] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_email] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_pass] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_mobile] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_status] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [show] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_type] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_name] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_email] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_mobile] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_status] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [edit_account] => Array
                    (
                        [user_name] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_email] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_pass] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_mobile] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_avatar] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [user_name] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_email] => Array
                            (
                                [rules] => required|valid_email|is_unique[er_users.user_email]
                            )

                        [user_pass] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_pconf] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [lost] => Array
                    (
                        [user_email] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [reset] => Array
                    (
                        [user_email] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_code] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_pass] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [delete] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => hidden
                            )

                    )

            )

        [fields] => Array
            (
            )

        [createBy] => 
        [updateBy] => 
        [permission] => 
        [relations] => Array
            (
            )

        [user_id] => 1
        [user_type] => 1
        [user_name] => Admin User
        [user_email] => admin@localhost.local
        [user_pass] => $2y$10$sbJV7LZNE2/1RQ5SHyeqWeOIhhU0aXgq7uXQHfID/g9K5tJLENOja
        [user_mobile] => 
        [user_avatar] => 
        [user_code] => 0
        [user_create_by] => 0
        [user_update_by] => 0
        [user_create_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [user_update_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [user_status] => 2
    )
```

)

the below code is where the session is set

```
if($auth_driver->login($input['email'], $input['password'], $input['remember']))
    {
        $userdata = $this->user->row(array('user_email'=>$input['email']));
        // if user is not existed, create it
        if (!is_object($userdata)) {
            // create the user and make it active
            $newuser = new User_model;
            $newuser->user_type     = User_model::TYPE_USER;
            $newuser->user_name     = $input['email'];
            $newuser->user_email    = $input['email'];
            $newuser->user_pass     = $input['password'];
            $newuser->user_mobile   = '';
            $newuser->user_avatar   = '';
            $newuser->user_status   = User_model::STATUS_ACTIVE;
            $newuser->save();
            // load the user info
            $userdata = $this->user->row(array('user_email'=>$input['email']));
        }
    }


    if(isset($userdata) && is_object($userdata) && isset($userdata->user_id)) {
        // check if the account is active 
        if($userdata->user_status == User_model::STATUS_ACTIVE) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('userdata', $userdata);
            redirect('/User/Dashboard');
        } else {
            unset($userdata);
            set_message('activate_your_account', 'error');
            redirect('/Auth/Activate');
        }
    } else {
        set_message('wrong_email_or_password', 'error');
    }
    redirect('/Auth/Login');
}
```

I want you to help me access the user_id in the userdata

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access session variables in codeigniter ,

```
$this->session->userdata("session name here");
```

See [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i try $this->session->userdata("user_name"); and print it but it has no value

Comment: thank you very much  , yes please could you help me fetch that array in order to get the user_id ?

Comment: use this, `echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->session->userdata());` and add the output to your question.

Comment: try this, `$this->session->userdata("user_id")`

Comment: if it is not working, add the code where you are setting the session.

Comment: try `$this->session->userdata()->user_id;`

Comment: hello it works without the session  like this :$this->userdata->user_id; thank you in advance

Comment: i already give the answer a rank up , there is something else i have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

according to your session dump :

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
```